# What is the virtual page size on windows

Tags: windows, memory-management

On linux this can be found by running

```
getconf PAGESIZE
```

How can this parameter be found on Windows?  Is it even a parameter, or just a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[From wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29)**

> Windows-based operating systems Win32-based operating systems,
>   such as those in the Windows 9x and Windows NT families, may use the
>   system function *GetSystemInfo()* from *kernel32.dll.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>     
int main(void) 
{   
    SYSTEM_INFO si;     
    GetSystemInfo(&si);     
    printf("The page size for this system is %u bytes.\n", si.dwPageSize);      
    return 0; 
}
```

I couldn't find any direct command that you can run to find it out.

Comment: Thanks.  I found you can access that in .NET too [link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getsysteminfo)